# Laravel : Passing extra parameter on Collection filtering

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

the idea it's quite simple, however I have not yet been able to materialize it.

Here's the code

(I've changed the name of the variables to describe their use)

```
    $games = Game::all();
    $games_already_added = $member->games()->lists('id');

    $games = $games->filter(function($game){
        global $games_already_added;
        if(!in_array($game->id,$games_already_added)){
            return true;
        }   
    });
```

When the code is executed I receive the error

`in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

I have verified that the variable `$games_already_added` is defined on the outer scope and contains items.

**Is there any way I could pass the `$games_already_added` variable as a parameter on the collection's filter function ?**

Any kind of suggestion's or guidance are highly appreciated !

Thank you!

Comment: Or you can just do `return !in_array($game->id,$games_already_added)`

Comment: @djay indeed djay , but my issue here was not being able to access to the games_already_added array , however , thanks for the shorter line!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It's not global, but `use` that works with a Closure:

```
$games = $games->filter(function($game) use ($games_already_added) {
    if(!in_array($game->id,$games_already_added)){
        return true;
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thank you once again @deczo! This will sure come handy !

Comment: Grrr I knew I needed `use` but was forgetting to wrap arguments in parentheses

Answer (score 3):

This isn't strictly what you're trying to do - but it looks like it's what you want to achieve.

```
$games_already_added = $member->games()->lists('id');
$games = Game::whereNotIn('id', $games_already_added)->get();
```

But if you really want to do the filtering, @deczo's answer is the way to go.